# Dynamically generating method names in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to generate links in my views using the url helpers such as user_path(@user), the catch is, in some cases I don't know what model I am creating this link for i.e. whether it is a user or a store or someting else

I would like to be able to determine this on the fly and call the appropriate view helper, currently I am doing the following, but I am wondering if there is a drier way of doing it.

```
if object.class == "Store"
   store_path(object)
elsif object.class == "User"
   user_path(object)
...etc
```

Comment: Show us the full code please. Where are you writing this code? Helper? Model? Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`url_for(object)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002141) does what you need:

> If you instead of a hash pass a record
>   (like an Active Record or Active
>   Resource) as the options parameter,
>   you‘ll trigger the named route for
>   that record. The lookup will happen on
>   the name of the class. So passing a
>   `Workshop` object will attempt to use
>   the `workshop_path` route.

If you are using [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002142), then you can just pass the object as the URL:

```
<%= link_to 'Title', object %>
```

Comment: This is what rails does internally, form_for and link_to among others just wraps url_for. You can choose whether you want a full URL or just the path with the :only_path option.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, use send to dynamically choose the method name

```
send("#{object.class.name.downcase}_path", object)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. this works nicely for any pathname that I want to construct :)